# I cannot get rid of "Method is undefined for type romanCalculator error along with illegal modifiers what is the issue?

Tags: java, methods, invoke, roman-numerals

Sorry if this is a simple error, I am still very new to Java and have trouble with all the rules. I am trying to create a calculator that takes in roman numerals, converts them to integers, them performs operations with them, and then converts them back roman numerals to print by calling methods. I put this together looking at some examples and it seems to almost all work out except for the convertFromRoman method. If anyone sees any other errors please let me know because I really feel lost. Heres the code:

```
package roman_calculator;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class RomanCalculator {
    public static Scanner kbInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static String doMath(char operator, int firstNum, int secondNum) {
        switch (operator) {
        case '+':
           return convertToRoman(firstNum + secondNum);
        case '-':
           return convertToRoman(firstNum - secondNum);
        case '*':
           return convertToRoman(firstNum * secondNum);
        case '/':
           return convertToRoman(firstNum / secondNum);
           
        }
        
        return "omething";
        
        /*
         * This method will perform the arithmetic
         * indicated by the operator (+ -* /),
         * invoke convertToRoman to convert answer to Roman number,
         * then return answer
         * */
    }

    public static char getOperator() {
        System.out.println("please choose an operator: +, - , * , or /");
        return kbInput.next().charAt(0);
    }

    public static int getOperands(int which) {
        while (true) {
            System.out.print("Enter operand" + ": ");
            String roman = kbInput.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            int romanNum = convertFromRoman(roman);
            if (romanNum >= 0)
             return romanNum;
            else
             System.out.println("Bad operand, please try again");
        
        
        /*This routine should prompt the user to enter Roman number. 
      convertFromRoman needs to be invoked to convert the Roman number to an integer.
      If the input is invalid (-1 returned from convertFromRoman)
      then complain and prompt the user again. 
    */ 
    }
    public static int convertFromRoman(String roman) {
        
               int result = 0;

               for (int i = 0; i < roman.length(); i++) {

                int s1 = num(roman.charAt(i));

                if (s1 < 0) {
                 System.out.println("Invalid operand");
                 
                }
                if (i + 1 < roman.length()) {
                 int s2 = num(roman.charAt(i + 1));
                 if (s2 < 0) {
                  System.out.println("Invalid operand");
                  
                 }

                 if (s1 >= s2) {
                  result = result + s1;
                 } else {
                  result = result + s2 - s1;
                  i++;
                 }
                } else {
                 result = result + s1;
                 i++;
                }
               }

               return result;
            
            }
        /*
         * This method will convert Roman number to integer
         * return -1 when input is invalid
         * 
         * */
    }
    public static String convertToRoman(int num) {
        System.out.println(num);
        String roman = "";
        while (num > 0) {
           while (num >= 1000) {
            roman = roman + "M";
            num -= 1000;
           }
           while (num >= 500) {
            roman = roman + "M";
            num -= 500;
           }
           while (num >= 100) {
            roman = roman + "D";
            num -= 100;
           }
           while (num >= 50) {
            roman = roman + "C";
            num -= 50;
           }
           while (num >= 10) {
            roman = roman + "X";
            num -= 10;
           }
           while (num >= 5) {
            roman = roman + "V";
            num -= 5;
           }
           while (num >= 1) {
            roman = roman + "I";
            num -= 1;
           }
        }
        return roman;
        }

        static int num (char r) {
        if (r == 'I')
           return 1;
        if (r == 'V')
           return 5;
        if (r == 'X')
           return 10;
        if (r == 'L')
           return 50;
        if (r == 'C')
           return 100;
        if (r == 'D')
           return 500;
        if (r == 'M')
           return 1000;
        return -1;
        
        /*
         * This method will convert integer to Roman number
         * */
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String result;
        do {

            result = doMath(getOperator(), getOperands(), getOperands());

            System.out.println(result);
            System.out.println("do you want to continue? y/n");
            kbInput.nextLine();
        } while (kbInput.nextLine().charAt(0) == 'y');
        System.out.println("Have a nice day!");
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Normally you would need to be more specific. "it seems to almost all work out except for the convertFromRoman method. If anyone sees any other errors please let me know because I really feel lost." -> this is too vague. If you're unsure, you can still suggest other things you think may be wrong and why you think so.

Answer (score 0):

You have a missing `}` in the following code, the last `}` was missing.

```
public static int getOperands(int which) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter operand" + ": ");
        String roman = kbInput.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        int romanNum = convertFromRoman(roman);
        if (romanNum >= 0)
         return romanNum;
        else
         System.out.println("Bad operand, please try again");
    }
}
```

And you need to remove the last `}` from the methode `convertFromRoman`.

Also there is a error in the line `result = doMath(getOperator(), getOperands(), getOperands());` where you either need to pass a parameter to `getOperands()` or change the method signiture to `getOperator()` or whatever you are trying.

A tip for you: Formating your code makes it easier to read and see the layers (e.g for Eclispe IDE is it `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `F`)

Comment: Thank you so much, I cant believe I didn't catch that. I have one more question if you don't mind, maybe I will have to posts new question but for ```getOperand``` It asks me for twice (e.g Console Output:```please choose an operator: +, - , * , or /
*
Enter operand: Enter operand: xx
0

do you want to continue? y/n ``` as the program is reading it as 20*0=0 not 10*10.)
  and I assume it allows me two inputs but I am not sure how to input two separate values. Do you see the issue?